# Types from COM DLL not available to my VC++ code after '#import "MyDll.dll"'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-errors, com

I'm a COM newbie trying to make a dirt-simple C++ console app to test consuming a COM DLL.  In my lone .cpp file, I include the line

```
#import "AgLeaderFile.dll"
```

to import the COM DLL of interest.  I added the DLL's directory to "Executable Directories" in Project Properties->Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories.  I know it is being found, because the red squiggles under the `#import` directive disappeared when I added this path, and a .tlh file is getting generated in the project's output directory when I build.

Unfortunately, when I refer to types declared in the .tlh file, I get "undeclared identifier" errors (C2065).  It seems like the compiler isn't finding the .tlh file.

[image: undeclared identifier squiggles]

What is the correct way to make the types from the generated .tlh file available to my .cpp file?  I thought the `#import` statement was supposed to be enough.  Do I need to add $(TargetDir) as an additional include directory or something?  (That sounds hacky.)

Answer (score 1):

The types I was trying to reference were in a namespace.  Adding a `using namespace AgLeaderFileLib` fixed my problem.